# GTK+ gio No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm using VC++ 2008 and I've the code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

And in every compiler i get same error: **gio/gio.h: No such file or directory.**

I've added this libs:
gtk-win32-2.0.lib
gdk-win32-2.0.lib
gailutil.lib

What else can i do?

EDIT: I've added includes and bins.
The error is at gdkapplaunchcontext.h > line 30 > #include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to install gtk includes (the folder with `gtk.h`) and specify that path in the *Include paths* of your compiler.

---

Also be aware that GTK depends on several other libraries, including **`gobject`** and **`glib`**. You will need to install them too.

Comment: I did. The error is at gdkapplauchcontext.h > line 30> #include <gio/gio.h>

Comment: @robik Install also `gobject` and `glib` libraries. Gtk depends on them.

Comment: This has not fixed the problem for me, searching my entire hard drive I don't have the gio directory or gio.h anywhere.  I have tried every download available from GTK nothing includes these files...  More answers please

Comment: @DanMayor, please read the comments above: you also need to install the `gobject` and `glib` libraries, because Gtk depends on them.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @ulidtko said, if you get this error in a typical GTK+ app you need to:

1. Install the necessary libs. E.g.  for Debian-based distros:

   sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
2. Use the neccessary include paths and libs to compile. E.g. in your makefile:

   myprog : myprog.c
       gcc -o $@ $< $(shell pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0) $(shell pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0)