# I can't build opencv_contrib in C++ on kaggle

Tags: c++, opencv, build, kaggle

I am trying to build opencv with contrib on kaggle notebook...
following these commands:

```
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
%cd /kaggle/working/opencv
!git checkout 4.4.0
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
%cd /kaggle/working/opencv/opencv_contrib
!git checkout 4.4.0
%cd /kaggle/working/opencv/
!mkdir build
%cd build
!cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/kaggle/working/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules /kaggle/working/opencv
!make
```

This is the cmake ouput:
[cmake_output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4_B5UcmwznGHkC9YOIRTslNwV0hYRvN/view?usp=sharing)

when building I got the following error:
.
.
.

```
In file included from /opt/conda/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /opt/conda/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from /kaggle/working/opencv-4-4-0-contrib-j/opencv_4_4_0_contrib/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:48:
/opt/conda/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30:10: fatal error: gio/gio.h: No such file or directory
   30 | #include <gio/gio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:89: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_gtk.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5990: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

I would appreciate the help:

Comment: This is the CMAKE output:

Comment: Try to install `gobject` and `glib` libraries. Gtk depends on them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4700035/18667225

Comment: Already tried... no problem on my home notebook, but ok kaggle it is not working.